# How to implement HttpDaemon

Tags: http-daemon

I am a Java Programmer.I have to implement HttpDaemon.I think it would be written in 'C' or 'Perl' . Kindly help me in what is it and How to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read and understand all the relevant specs.
2. Code it up. Start with `java.net.ServerSocket`.

The first step is the hard one!

Seriously, there are many industrial-strength web servers written in Java: [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), [Jigsaw](http://www.w3.org/Jigsaw/), etc. [Here is a long list of them.](http://java-source.net/open-source/web-servers)

Perhaps of most interest to you would be [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), which is designed to be embedded into other applications. Use Jetty, rather than writing your own. It's a large undertaking to do a good job, and why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I know java.net.ServerSocket.but what is the use of HttpDaemon.Is there any link or pdf to read it